# How to stop Jenkins from breaking UI?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My **build names** are quite large and cannot be shortened, **Jenkins 1.572** seems to be unable to handle large names and break UI (refer to image). I found [a plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin) to set build name, in my case I've set it as build number but the plugin only does this after the building process is complete (refer to build #31 to #35 in the image). This means UI still breaks.

Is there any plugin available to do this? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrade to 1.571, or wait for 1.576 to be released that will include a fix. From the [changelog](http://jenkins-ci.org/changelog), *Upcoming changes*:

> Modernized sidebar `<l:pane>`s and making them work better with new layout. (issue 23810)